# Webcam works for a couple of hours, then Pi refuses to detect it

Tags: usb, webcam

I am currently playing around with a Trust WB-1400T webcam. While this is "unsupported", I got it to work with motion.

After a couple of hours of playing, I noticed that motion failed to connect to the device a lot. I decided to move my camera from the "original" raspberry pi USB ports to my connected hub. (This is stupid, as this is not a powered hub). However, the camera was not detected!

I tried the following:

- Reboot ("Panic" solution)
- *lsusb* doesn't show my webcam
- *modprobe gspca_main* (this was the mod used) doesnt work
- *dmesg* doesn't show anything when removing/readding
  my webcam
- Connected the cam to another box which uses arch. Is
  detected after using *lsusb*.
- Removed all devices from usb. Another
  *lsusb*. Failed.

Any ideas how this is possible? Clearly, the webcam is not broken as it is detected on my arch box.

Everything is up to date.

Answer (score -1):

Motion is the culprit. It works for different times for different users, then disconnects from cam. It happened to me also, so I googled for a solution and there are lots of people having the same problem. Requests from the author of Motion results in nothing

Comment: Do you have a link to any forum where the author comments on this?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=30827